# Buffer overflow in a function that seem to be fine

Tags: c, buffer, stack-overflow, bmp

If I load a picture with a number of diverse pixels, something causes buffer overflow somewhere in this function:

```
typedef unsigned char color[3];

unsigned long
olor_replace_data
(unsigned char *buff, unsigned char old_r, unsigned char old_g, unsigned char old_b, unsigned char new_r, unsigned char new_g, unsigned char new_b)
{
    unsigned long pixels_replaced = 0, i;
    unsigned long image_size = extract_num_data(&buff[2], 4); // this function extracts a number from n bytes
    unsigned long image_width = get_width_data(buff), image_height = 0; // this function obtains the width of the memory-buffered image.
    color new_color, current_color = {0, 0, 0};

    new_color[0] = new_b;
    new_color[1] = new_g;
    new_color[2] = new_r;

    for(i = 54; i < image_size; i += 3)
    {
        if(i == 54 + (image_width * (image_height+1)))
        {
            image_height++;
            i += image_width % 4;
        }

        memcpy(current_color, &buff[i], 3);

        if(current_color[0] == old_b && current_color[1] == old_g && current_color[2] == old_r)
        {
            memmove(&buff[i-3], new_color, 3);
            pixels_replaced++;
        }
    }
    return pixels_replaced;
}
```

..But I am unable to locate it.

It says that the line responsible for this is

`memcpy(current_color, &buff[i], 3);` which is a bit hard to believe.

What could be wrong with this function?

Comment: I don't know about that specific line, but the top-limit of the outer-for-loop look odd. If the image size less-54 is not an *exact* multiple of 3 your loop will access image data beyond the image region on its tail. Knowing the exact addressable size of the `buff` region as-passed to this function wouldn't be a bad thing to include. in your question.Debug output of `image_size` , `image_width`, etc, also nice. A hex bin array of the actual image data would be the cats whiskers.

Comment: @WhozCraig the entire pixel array must be multiple of 3.

Comment: The dimensions of the image that failed are `450 309`

Comment: And the actual numbers gleaned from the head bytes by `extract_num_data` and `get_width_data` for `image_width` and `image_size` are...?

Comment: ..correct. Because I am using these functions on 13 more functions. You may be right about the image's buffer being overpassed, because of the `+3` devotion.

Comment: I didn't ask whether they were "correct" or not. What are their *values* ? (i.e. a `fprintf(stderr, ...)` says...?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't check this easily on the platform I am working on.

Comment: Well, that is a possible issue. I concur with you, I see little way `memcpy(current_color, &buff[i], 3)` will *overwrite* a buffer overflow, but a *overread* seems plausible. If `image_size` really is the number of r, g, and b values, then `image_size-2` would be the limit to shoot. (don't hold me to that, btw, I'm *severely* hopped up on cold meds right now coming down from a nasty flu and things are little .. spacey. My math may be off by one somewhere.)

Comment: when acquiring the length of each line in the image data, (given this seems to be working with .BMP image) each line must be a multiple of 4 in length.  I do not see where the code is making that correct for the line length.  That magic number '54' is not always correct.  the code should use the value in the field that is embedded in the first header of the .BMP file to get the offset to the image data.  One of the headers in the .BMP file will indicate the actual width of each pixel.  That information should be used, rather than assuming the width is 24 bits

Comment: the file header(s) contain the width of each pixel in bits, the number of pixels in width, and the number of pixels in height.  suggest using those actual values rather than making the assumptions I see in the code.  and %4 will give the wrong answer, as the actual width of a row of the image in bytes requires the pixel width * bytes per pixel, rounded up to a multiple of 4

Comment: @AlanSalios, the entire data/pixel array must be a multiple of 4, because each row must be a multiple of 4 bytes wide.

Comment: the padding, if any, on each pixel row of the image is not part of the displayed image, so should not be treated to the check for the search pixel value.

Comment: @user3629249 Certainly you are on the right track.  Bet OP's problem goes away when the picture width is a multiple of 4.

Comment: I don't understand how could all say this while the exist of `i += image_width % 4;`